# setStreamVolume sound notification

Tags: android

When I use setStreamVolume or physical sound buttons to adjust the volume on my device, it produces short sound notifications(beeps) - how do I remove it ?

Right now I have something like:

```
_audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, (int) ((_maxVolume / 100) * progress),AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace FLAG_PLAY_SOUND with 0

```
_audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, (int) ((_maxVolume / 100) * progress), 0);
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way. I wasn't able to find a FLAG in the AudioManage to accomplish this.